# Composite multiple images using OpenCL and Python: Kernel image2d_array_t?

Tags: python, opencv, opencl, pyopencl

As I'm exploring some ways to composite (custom overlay) multiple images into one and I found this great article https://towardsdatascience.com/get-started-with-gpu-image-processing-15e34b787480. My only issue is that I need to pass multiple buffers to the kernel as an argument and not one.

So, in python I created a list with multiple buffers

```py
inImgsBuffers = [cl.Image(context, cl.mem_flags.READ_ONLY, cl.ImageFormat(cl.channel_order.RGBA, cl.channel_type.UNORM_INT8), shape=inShape) for inImg in inImgs]
```

and then tried passing them as the argument

```
kernel.set_arg(0, inImgsBuffers) # input image buffer
```

Then, on Kernel I thought to use the image2d_array_t instead of image2d_t

```
__kernel void morphOpKernel(__read_only image2d_array_t ins, __write_only image2d_t out)
```

but I'm getting the following error.

> pyopencl._cl.LogicError: Kernel.set_arg failed: INVALID_VALUE - invalid kernel argument

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`image2d_array_t` is a special OpenCL type. So, it is not possible to create the list of `pyopencl.Image` objects and pass it to the kernel. Instead of it, you need to create the object of `pyopencl.Image` with special format that means that it is an array of 2D images:

```py
inImgsBufFlags = cl.mem_flags.READ_ONLY
inImgsFormat = cl.ImageFormat(cl.channel_order.RGBA,
                              cl.channel_type.UNORM_INT8)
# shape of cl.Image is a tuple that contains
# (image_width, image_height, image_array_size)
inImgsShape = inShape + (len(inImgs),)
inImgsBuffers = cl.Image(context, inImgsBufFlags, inImgsFormat,
                         shape=inImgsShape, is_array=True)

kernel.set_arg(0, inImgsBuffers)
```